# Alloy Wheels Ford SportKA

Tags: ford, wheels

My Ford SportKA 1.6 2005 recently failed its MOT, due to the rear wheels being distorted.

The part number of the alloy wheels are 3S51-AB, Wheel width - 6J, PCD - 4X108, Offset - ET34.

However i was only able to get 1 of these, I have found a different set of alloys that is identical in design and specifications but used on a Ford StreetKA with part number: 3S51-AA, Wheel width - 6J, PCD - 4X108, Offset - ET34.

Is it safe to assume i can use the 3S51-AA on my car?

Answer (score 1):

If the width, offset and PCD are the same, then yes, it's fairly safe to assume they can be used. The only other number to be aware of the is the centre bore (i.e. the size of the hole in the middle), but I doubt there'd be any difference in this case - in fact I suspect they're exactly the same, and the differing part number is down to some trivial difference - colour perhaps?